# Bootstrap tooltip position not working in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I am trying to show a tooltip on popover on a small image using bootstrap 3.

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4  text-right">
    <span  class="warning-tooltip-icon" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" 
           title="To have a better match result we need you to know about your language level"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.warning-tooltip-icon{
    background-image:url(/img/exclamation-icon.png); 
    width: 17px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**JS**:

```
 $(".warning-tooltip-icon").tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

Its working perfectly in desktop pc, but in mobile device the tooltip message shows on different place.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your grid classes are extremely redundant; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Comment: I tried only to adding class col-sm-4, but it not working. If I move the icon into the new row then its work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('[title]').attr("data-rel", "tooltip");
        $("[data-rel='tooltip']")
            .attr("data-placement", "top")
            .attr("data-content", function () {
            return $(this).attr("title")
        })
            .removeAttr('title');
        var showPopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('show');
        };
        var hidePopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        };
        $("[data-rel='tooltip']").popover({
            trigger: 'manual'
        }).click(showPopover).hover(showPopover, hidePopover);
    });
});
```

Use it like this:

```
<span class="warning-tooltip-icon" title="To have a better match result we need you to know about your language level"></span>
```

Comment: I applied this code. Its show and hide perfectly, but position is misplaced. On mobile view the title not show on the top, it shows different place(far away from the element), Its good on desktop.

Comment: Then the problem is in your wrapper element

Answer (score -1):

Yes I used redundant class, I changed my Html code. But still there same problem. 
**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
<span  class="warning-tooltip-icon" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" 
       title="To have a better match result we need you to know about your language level"></span>
```

Its working fine on mobile as well as desktop if I changed the html code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<span  class="warning-tooltip-icon" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" 
       title="To have a better match result we need you to know about your language level"></span>
```